# A regex expression, that works fine on Apache, but fails on nginx

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, nginx, preg-replace

I have a following regex expression which works well in apache but doesn't in nginx.

```
 preg_replace("/(src=\")(.*)([^>]*)(".$base_url_mod."\/)/",
  "data-$1$2$3", $content);
```

If I remove `(".$base_url_mod."\/)/` it started to work but that's not what I want.

**Full function:**

```
function tt_type_filter ( $content ) {
    $post_type = get_post_type();

    if($post_type == 'page' || $post_type == 'post') {
        $tt_connector = get_option ( 'tt_connector' );
        $base_url = get_site_url();

        $base_url_arr = parse_url($base_url);
        $base_url_mod = $base_url_arr[scheme]. '\:\/\/' .$base_url_arr[host]. '\\' .$base_url_arr[path];

        if($tt_connector == $base_url) 
            return preg_replace("/(src=\")(.*)([^>]*)(".$base_url_mod."\/)/", "data-$1$2$3", $content);
        else 
            return preg_replace("/(src=\")(.*)([^>]*)(uploads\/)/", "data-$1$3", $content);
    }
}
```

**Eg.(Purpose of this expression)**

`http://wp.mysite.net/wp4/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/someimage.jpg`
should be replaced with
`http://api.mydomain.com/images/domain/2012/10/someimage.jpg`

Comment: Does it help if you call [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) on `$base_url_mod`?  Perhaps the nginx version is leaving a `/` that's breaking your regex.  Have you compared the values of `$base_url_mod` on the two servers?

Comment: @Hobo Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix it at my own.

The issue was with `$base_url_mod`. It was adding `\/` at the end of the path when `$base_url_arr[path]`having empty/no value. So I'd to put a condition in the function and it started to work.

**Here is an updated function: *(works fine on both, apache and nginx)***

```
function tt_type_filter ( $content ) {
    $post_type = get_post_type();

    if($post_type == 'page' || $post_type == 'post') {
        $tt_connector = get_option ( 'tt_connector' );
        $base_url = get_site_url();

        $base_url_arr = parse_url($base_url);
        if ($base_url_arr[path]) {
            $base_url_mod = $base_url_arr[scheme]. '\:\/\/' .$base_url_arr[host]. '\\' .$base_url_arr[path];
        } else {
            $base_url_mod = $base_url_arr[scheme]. '\:\/\/' .$base_url_arr[host];
        }

        if($tt_connector == $base_url)
            return preg_replace("/(src=\")(.*)([^>]*)(".$base_url_mod."\/)/", "data-$1$2$3", $content);
        else
            return preg_replace("/(src=\")(.*)([^>]*)(uploads\/)/", "data-$1$3", $content);
    }
}
```